# When running the Apex Test as Community User, User's Contact Record is always Empty

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, code-coverage, contact

I'm trying to run an Apex test case as a Community User. I've populated my data inside a @TestSetup method and when I run the test case User Record has a ContactId but there is no Contact Record associated to the User's ContactId. Here is my code block.

```
    static void setupData() {

        Id profileId = [select id from profile where name=: 'Partner Community User'].id;
        Account ac = new Account(name = 'ACME Co') ;
        insert ac;

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test_Contact'
        ,AccountId = ac.Id
        ,ANEM_BState__c = 'Paris'
        ,ANEM_BCountry__c = 'France'
        ,Email = 'testCommunityUsermig123@test.com'
        ,Marketing_Status__c = 'Active'
        ,Should_receive_pricing_communications__c = 'No'
        ,Account_type__c = 'Broker'
        ,Title = 'Journalist');
        insert con;

        System.debug('@mal-CON-ID'+con.Id);

        User communityUser = new User(alias = 'comUser'
        ,email = 'testCommunityUsermig123@test.com'
        ,emailencodingkey='UTF-8'
        ,lastname = 'Batman'
        ,languagelocalekey='en_US'
        ,localesidkey='en_US'
        ,profileid = profileId
        ,country = 'France'
        ,IsActive = true
        ,ContactId = con.Id
        ,timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles'
        ,username = 'testCommunityUsermig123@test.com');
        insert communityUser;
    }


     @IsTest
     static void testMyProfileLogicForFetchAccounts() {
     Test.startTest();
     List<User> lstUsers = [SELECT Id,ContactId,ANEM_BCountry__c FROM 
     User WHERE username =: 'testCommunityUsermig123@test.com' LIMIT 1];
     //These debug logs have values
     system.debug('@mal-user'+lstUsers[0].Contact.ANEM_BCountry__c); //has a value
     System.debug('@mal-contact-Id:'+lstUsers[0].ContactId);//has a value
     //Logic to check
     WhoIsWhoController.getwhoIsWhoContacts()
     Test.stopTest();
    }

    ---------------------------Actual Logic-----------------------------------
    //Contact Query is giving me null values to User's related contact
    public class WhoIsWhoController{

    @AuraEnabled
        public static List<ContactWrapper> getwhoIsWhoContacts() {

    System.debug('@mal-User-NAME'+UserInfo.getName()); // Giving me correct community user's name
            User communityUser   = [SELECT Id,Name,ContactId, Contact.ANEM_BCountry__c, Contact.ANEM_BState__c, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];

            //for debug
            System.debug('@mal-CONT_ID:'+communityUser.ContactId); // has a Id value
            System.debug('@mal-Contact.Name:'+communityUser.Contact.Name); //Giving me null
            System.debug('@mal-Contact.ANEM_BState__c:'+communityUser.Contact.ANEM_BState__c);//Giving me null

    }

    }
```

I've checked the profile permissions also. All are full accessible.
Any Idea guys, why I'm getting null values for User's Contact Fields ?

- communityUser.Contact.Name
- communityUser.Contact.ANEM_BState__c

Appreciate your help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely this is a sharing issue rather than a profile (crud) issue. To verify, append the [without sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) keyword to your **WhoIsWhoController** as so:

```
public without sharing class WhoIsWhoController {
// ... logic here
}
```

Run your test again and, if the Contact record becomes visible to the community user, it is indeed a sharing issue. If that's the case, you can leave your class as-is (without sharing), or adjust your sharing schema as necessary.